# Use JpaRepository to create findByEmail method which is similer to findById

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've a Spring Boot project with the following DAO:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    
    // method to sort by last name
    public List<User> findAllByOrderByLastNameAsc();

}
```

It also has a service with the following findById():

```
@Override
public User findById(int theId) {
    Optional<User> result = userRepository.findById(theId);
        
    User theUser = null;
    if(result.isPresent()) {
        theUser = result.get();
    }
    else {
        // we didn't find the user
        throw new RuntimeException("Did not find userId: " + theId);
    }
    return theUser;
}
```

I want to create a similar findByEmail(). The following won't work because `JpaRepository` doesn't have a findByEmail method:

```
@Override
public User findByEmail(String theEmail) {
        
    Optional<User> result = userRepository.findByEmail(theEmail);
    User theUser = null;
    if(result.isPresent()) {
        theUser = result.get();
    }
    else {
        // we didn't find the user
        throw new RuntimeException("Did not find userId: " + theUser);
    }
    return theUser;
}
```

I think my findByEmail() method should query User with the email address to get the ID then call findById with it. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can create a method

```
List<User> findByEmail(String emailAddress);
```

in your DAO.

Take a look a this page

(https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html)

in the section : "query creation" .

Comment: OK thanks. I tried that. I'm seeing a `UsernameNotFoundException`. When I run debugger everything liiks correct. I can't see the exact query that's getting executed though. Is there any way I can see the it?

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to see the executed query. But in the link attached in my answer, in the section query creation, the first example demonstrates how the method findByEmailAddress&Lastname is translated into a query. For the problem of the UsernameNotFoundException please ask a new answer so that community could help you.